# Three new lines before rendering anything in CakePHP breaks ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, http-headers

I need a function in CakePHP **1.3** which to render a value used by jquery function but it always renders three new lines before the value which breaks the jquery. Setting any of these `headers` did not help

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
header('Content-Type: text/x-json');
header("X-JSON: ".$content);
echo $content;
```

the jquery uses:

```
var content = $.ajax({ url: /link/to/cakephp/function ,async: false }).responseText;
```

Can I fix those three lines or the jquery function?

Comment: Do you have `$this->layout = 'ajax'` in your view?

Comment: already tried `$this->autoRender = false;` or 
  `$this->layout = 'ajax';` when `autoRender` is set to `false` i display the value just in the controller, if true i make a view. But no matter what always I get the 3 empty lines before the view/value is rendered

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove extra whitespace and linebreaks:

```
echo trim( $content );
```

Comment: those lines are not from the variable

Answer (score 0):

The file with the headers. Is that rendered as HMTL? If do, what is the doc-type? I vaguely remember having a similar issues before. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue.. Its ?> in the end of config files with newlines following.
Remove the ?> and the newlines and you lose the "\n\n\n"...